# Is it possible to make a image carousel that can change section when scrolling instead of clicking? - Angular Typescript PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a 3 image carousel designed with PrimeNG. Each image is associated to a specific text, when I change the image everything else changes, so far everything works correctly.

The problem is that I am only able to change the image when I click on the arrows and not when I scroll over it.

HTML

```
<p-carousel
          [showNavigators]="false"
          [value]="cars"
          [numVisible]="1"
          [numScroll]="1"
          orientation="vertical"
          verticalViewPortHeight="400px"
          (onPage)="changeSelectedCar($event)"
          [circular]="false"
        >
          <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
            <img
              [src]="car.image"
              alt="Carousel Image"
              class="carousel-image"
            />
          </ng-template>
        </p-carousel>
```

Typescript

````
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ecco-fleet',
  templateUrl: './ecco-fleet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ecco-fleet.component.scss'],
})
export class EccoFleetComponent {
  images: string[] = [
    '../../../../../assets/images/fleet_1.png',
    '../../../../../assets/images/fleet_2.png',
    '../../../../../assets/images/fleet_3.png',
  ];

  visible!: boolean;

  showDialog() {
    this.visible = true;
  }

  cars: any;
  selectedCar: any;
  changeSelectedCar(event: any) {
    const currentIndex = event.page;
    this.selectedCar = this.cars[currentIndex];
  }

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
      this.cars = [
        {
          title: this.translate.instant('carouselTtitle'),
          description:this.translate.instant('carouselText'),
          image: '../../../../../assets/images/fleet_1.png',
        },
        {
          title: this.translate.instant('carouselTtitle2'),
          description:this.translate.instant('carouselText2'),
          image: '../../../../../assets/images/fleet_2.png',
        },
        {
          title: this.translate.instant('carouselTtitle3'),
          description:this.translate.instant('carouselText3'),
          image: '../../../../../assets/images/fleet_3.png',
        },

      ];
      this.selectedCar = this.cars[0];
    });
  }
}```
````

Is there any way to achieve this? I have tried to make a carosuel without PrimeNG but in that case it doesn't work either.

Thank you very much for your help.